# Keycloak password reset email custom link

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

We use keycloak API rest to send email password reset to users.
The application can change the theme dynamically so we are using a wrapper for the authentication that's passing the requests to keycloak. As well we prefer not to expose keycloak.

To reset password we are doing an api request to

```
/admin/realms/${keycloakRealm}/users/${userId}/execute-actions-email
["UPDATE_PASSWORD"]
```

Is there any way we can change the host part of the url sent to the users in their email?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I've missed the obvious: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_replace

```
${"<url>"?replace("<partOfIt>", "<someOtherPart>")}
```